# Profiling underlying Linux OS functions/code like select() and poll()?

Tags: c++, c, performance, profiling, latency

If I was to write a tiny C or C++ application (on Linux) and call "native" Linux functions, such as select() and poll() when profiling, would I be able to see the assembler being used for these functions too, its not just user-written code which can be profiled?

I would be interested to see the assembly produced for various "native" Linux functions.

Comment: User-written functions are native too (unless written in JavaScript)...

Comment: So basically it wouldn't treat Linux poll(), select(), sendfile() etc any different from if I was polling my own functions?

Comment: Why not just read the source code for those functions?

Comment: @user315052 because the source code would be in C, not ASM?

Comment: Since you have the source, you can ask the compiler to output the assembler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. They are kernel calls, so you would see a bit of code up to kernel level.